# Blade I Can't Use Veriable Directly

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

When I try this;

```
<i class="down fa fa-arrow-down @if($post->is_down) active @endif"></i>
```

Active class not showing. But when I do that;

```
@php
$a = $post->is_down;
@endphp
<i class="down fa fa-arrow-down @if($a) active @endif"></i>
```

It's working well. Why that happening? How can I use it directly?

Note: **is_down** is appended veriable.

Function inside Post model file;

```
public function getIsDownAttribute($value){
        return $this->attributes['is_down'] = in_array(Auth::user()->id ?? 0,(array)json_decode($this->attributes['down']));
    }
```

Comment: try <i class="down fa fa-arrow-down {{$a?'active':''}}"></i>

Comment: Could you try `{{$post->is_down ?? 'active'}}` short and effective.

Comment: @JohnLobo when I use **$a** _(second code)_ it's working all kinds. But if I try this condition with **$post->is_down**, it's not working again.

Comment: @ORHANERDAY still not working. Btw **$post->is_down** veriable is coming from** is_array()** function.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info @ÖmerFarukDemirel, Could you please fully provide your `$post->is_down` in answer? I want clearly how it works.

Comment: try<i class="down fa fa-arrow-down  {{$post->is_down ? 'active':''}} ></i>

Comment: @ORHANERDAY I added it to question as extra information.

Comment: @JohnLobo not working. When I try out of i tag, it's working (other examples working too). But in i tag not working. Maybe it's because blade?

Comment: @ORHANERDAY; [Here](https://prnt.sc/bLBROohnSdag) (True) is my resault. Also I'm gettin same output in blade **@dump($post->is_down)** and **var_dump($post->is_down)** output is `bool(true)`

Comment: what about `{{$post->is_down}}` is that return `1`?

Comment: @ORHANERDAY yes it's true. Also I try : `@if($post->is_up == 1) active @endif` not working too

Comment: why did you use json_decode ? , is there a possibility that you are returning a string there ? will you please use gettype() on it ?

Comment: I am stumped. I hope it's a cache problem. Could you please run  `php artisan optimize:clear` after than put  `<i class="down fa fa-arrow-down {{$post->is_down ?? 'active'}}"></i>` ?

Comment: @ORHANERDAY; still not working... I'm stumped too. I try `@if($post->is_down) test @endif
        <i class="up fa fa-arrow-down @if($post->is_down) active @endif"></i>`. To sum up I put code out of i tag and it's working. Test displaying out of i. But in i tag not working. Also I try `@class(['active' => $post->is_down])` and it's not working too.

Comment: @HijenHEK; `boolean` is my output.

Comment: i am just guessing coz this is weird ! try and clear the view : php artisan view:clear.

Comment: Please check your blade name It should be Name.blade.php..so maybe you forget blade?

Comment: Can you create a new issue for Laravel [framework](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues)?

Comment: @AlyaAlSiyabi; it's successfully rendering.

Comment: @ORHANERDAY okay I'm creating thank u